# WCF to WPF - DataContract to Model

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

This might be an odd question, but its been nagging at me a little.

I'm looking at converting between datacontract objects on the WCF service and data models in the WPF client.

The way I see it there are three options:

1. Create objects on both WPF and WCF sides, and have a method that converts one to the other.
2. Create a single object, and use it on both sides.
3. Create an object on WPF side that wraps around the DataContract object returned from WCF service.

Now I was favoring 1. however I wondered if there was any downfalls i had not foreseen.

Comment: [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is your friend if you go with #1. That's what I used last time I faced this problem. :)

Comment: #3 is always a step up from #2. Most useful when the DTOs already implement INPC.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an excerpt from pp.81 of *"Prism 5 for WPF"* on *"The Model Class"*:

> Typically, the model represents the client-side domain model for the application. It can define data structures based on the application's data model and any supporting business and validation logic. The model may also include the code to support data access and caching, though typically a separate data repository or service is employed for this. Often, the model and data access layer are generated as part of a data access or service strategy, such as the ADO.NET Entity Framework, WCF Data Services, or WCF RIA Services.
>
> Typically, the model implements the facilities that make it easy to bind to the view. This usually means it supports property and collection changed notification through the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces. Models classes that represent collections of objects typically derive from the ObservableCollection class, which provides an implementation of the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.
>
> The model may also support data validation and error reporting through the IDataErrorInfo (or INotifyDataErrorInfo) interfaces. The IDataErrorInfo and INotifyDataErrorInfo interfaces allow WPF data binding to be notified when values change so that the UI can be updated. They also enable support for data validation and error reporting in the UI layer.
>
> **What if your model classes do not implement the required interfaces?**
>
> Sometimes you will need to work with model objects that do not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged, IDataErrorInfo, or INotifyDataErrorInfo interfaces. In those cases, the view model may need to wrap the model objects and expose the required properties to the view. The values for these properties will be provided directly by the model objects. The view model will implement the required interfaces for the properties it exposes so that the view can easily data bind to them.

I gather from this that the Word From On High is somewhere between #1 (use them directly) and #3 (use a wrapper), where the WCF proxy class is the Model and the wrapper class is your View Model.  As per the MVVM pattern, the Model (proxy) class should encapsulate business logic, while the View Model class should wrap the proxy class and incorporate presentation logic.

You would only add an extra model-wrapper around the proxy classes in those cases where you need them to support an additional interface such as `IDataErrorInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually better to define model for your View which you populates from the WCF data contracts. Some of the benefits:

1. Your UI will not be dependent on the Data Contracts, it will only be interested in its model which can be populated by any means.
2. Your UI models can contain properties which are the calculative ones to serve the particular view, so it is better to seperate them from Data Contracts.

Comment: This is what i was thinking, my models contain code my WCF doesnt care about.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)?  I would recommend having a View Model use the Data Contract either directly or through a wrapper.  This will enable you to decouple the View from the Data Contract.  The View should not contain any references to your Data Contract.